# Notepad++ custom folding keywords in existing language

Tags: notepad++, sql

I use notepad for sql code that has "REGION" blocks like the above that I would like to be able to fold

```
-- REGION MODE 3 - DELETE MODE
WHEN 3 THEN
DELETE FROM EDMX.M1_BRIEF WHERE ID = TID ;
SET STS_ID = 1 ;
SET STS_DESC = 'TEST'  ;
-- END REGION
```

I don't want to create a user defined language from start, can't I copy SQL settings somehow (styles, folding e.t.c.) and just add these folding keywords?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878241/how-to-create-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad-based-on-an-existing-language

Comment: @m4573r those answers are not very clear. I copied the settings, in those files (so now I have same settings for "sql" and "sql with regions") but I only see SQL in the language menu. I also created an "sql with regions" user-defined language but It does no hightlight or fold.

Comment: You're right, it's less helpful than I thought... I can't really find any simple solution expect from starting from scratch but using the keywords defined there as a base.